# Dynamic progress bar length based on value from getter in Vue2 and SCSS

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs2, getter

I am looking for a way (or ways) to dynamically set the length of my progress bar in scss in @keyframes (see comment in code). I am pulling the value from getters (getTasksFulfilmentRate) every time the value changes. My question is: how do I efficiently pass the value from html (or script) into the variable in scss so I can use in my style?

Hope the description is clear enough.

[simplified codepen example](https://codepen.io/mlvrkhn/pen/Vwbazpv)

my html

```
<div class="tasks-summary-container">
    <div class="progress">
        <div
            class="progress-value"
        >
            {{ getTasksFulfilmentRate }} %
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters('tasks', [
            'completedTaskCount',
            'notCompletedTaskCount',
            'getTasksFulfilmentRate',
        ]),
        ...mapState(['projects', 'activeFilter']),
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['setCategoryFilter']),
        filterCategory($event) {
            const selectedCategory = $event.target.getAttribute(
                'data-category'
            );
            this.setCategoryFilter(selectedCategory);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

store.js (fragment)

```
getters: {
        completedTaskCount: state => {
            return state.tasks.filter(task => task.isCompleted).length || 0;
        },
        notCompletedTaskCount: state => {
            return state.tasks.filter(task => !task.isCompleted).length || 0;
        },
        getTasksFulfilmentRate: (state, getters) => (getters.completedTaskCount / getters.getTotalTaskCount) * 100,
    },
```

scss:

```
.progress {
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border-radius: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 3px;
    display: flex;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    &-value {
        animation: load 2s normal forwards;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -10px;
        border-radius: 100px;
        background: variables.$primary-color;
        height: 20px;
        padding: 1px 0;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
        width: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes load {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: 70%; // here goes the value from getter
    }
}
```

Comment: a codepen would be helpful for someone to help you, as this is mostly a css/sass issue

Comment: added on the top now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom css property and use that property in style:

```
<div 
    class="tasks-summary-container" 
    :style="{
        '--progress-value': getTasksFulfilmentRate + '%' // custom css prop
    }"
>
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-value">
             70 %
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
@keyframes load {
    0% {
        width: 0;
    }
    100% {
        width: var(--progress-value) // here goes the value from getter
    }
}
```

Comment: yes! this is it! thank you very much. I was trying to approach the problem similar way but I must have confused some syntax between css and scss.